An anime tv show from the early 90's, that I can't seem to identify or find anywhere
Back in the early 90's, I used to wake up really early in the morning to watch this anime tv show that was only on at that time for me. 
It was essentially an anime version of Power Rangers. 
A group of young adults wearing magical armored suits fighting big monsters and mecha enemies in an urban environment. Each suit was a different color and granted each guy different powers and weapons. The red suited guy was their leader, and I believe they all had the ability to combine their powers into an ultimate white suit (worn by the red leader). I could be wrong on this last one.
I vaguely remember one episode where the red-suited leader was trapped in a painful ball of energy hurtling through space towards something particular, but I don't remember.
My memory is pretty vague because I was so young, but I do remember watching this show somewhere between the years 1993 and 1995 (I was born in 1988).
Please help me out if you recognize this show!

I'm afraid this might not be enough details. Here's a good place to start looking: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=saturday+morning+cartoons+1993&go=Go

This is a long shot. I was reminded of this when i read ur first 2 lines. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja_Senshi_Tobikage

One potential candidate is Voltron.

This series focuses on 5 lion robots and their pilots as they fight
  the evil forces of King Zarkon and Prince Lotor.


It could possibly be Ronin Warriors Which was about 5 resurrected warriors who had different weapons and powers corresponding to a different element. Ryo was the leader and he had a white tiger that followed him. They could all combine their powers into Ryo who would then wear a white suit of armor. Here is another link to a transformation clip see if it's familiar.

The OP stated that it was an anime. The show you mentioned is not.

@CL4PTR4P Good point I missed that somehow. Changing my answer.

That sounds more like what they are thinking. Too bad the transformations took forever. Reminded me of an episode of DBZ, lol.

Could also be Voltes V: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Ddenji_Machine_Voltes_V
Voltes V is a robot composed of five "Volt Machines", and each are themselves formidable weapons. Each machine is piloted by Ken'ichi (Steve), Daijiro (Big Bert), and Hiyoshi (Little Jon): the three sons of Kentaro and Mitsuyo Gō, along with the only daughter of General Oka; Megumi (Jamie Robinson), and Ippei Mine (Mark Gordon), an orphan cowboy.
